# Understanding wordpress permalinks and query string parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a wordpress theme from almost scratch and I come to this bump in the road.

I have this URL: http://localhost/mysite.com/wordpress/portfolio/

That shows a page of the template type "portfolio" that I have defined.

I'm trying to add a search box / results on that page and my problem is that this url:

http://localhost/mysite.com/wordpress/portfolio/?s=test&submit=Search

Does not show my portfolio page / template, but rather my home page.

If someone can explain to me what's going on, I'd appreciate it very much. Please go in technical details, I'm running a local copy of worpress on my WAMP and intend on releasing all this on my prod. server eventually.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say you are creating a theme from "almost scratch" could explain what that means?  Have you copied the twenty eleven theme and reworked it?  Does your theme contain a search.php file?

Comment: I copy over parts from 2011 theme only when I need it. Kind of a white list way of working. So I currently don't have a search.php page.

Comment: Here are a few links that can help you understand the way wordpress handles which template to serve.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 and 
http://yoast.com/wordpress-theme-anatomy/

Comment: My portfolio template leads to portfolio.php. I' wondering why the query parameters makes my site use index.php instead. The template hierarchy page helps me a bit Jrod, thanks I'll keep figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the search results page can be customised by providing a `search.php` within your theme. If this file is not present, then WordPress will use the theme's `index.php` instead.